# What's a good way to express typescript deep property access

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Trying to model the types for a function:

```
function getDeep (object, property) {
  return property.length <= 0 
    ? object 
    : getDeep(object[property[0]], property.slice(1))
}
```

Getting somewhere with typescript 4.1:

```
type DeepProperty<O, P> = P extends []
    ? O
    : P extends [infer F, ...infer R]
    ? F extends keyof O ? DeepProperty<O[F], R> : undefined
    : undefined

function getDeep<O, P extends string[]> (obj: O, prop: P): DeepProperty<O, P> {}
```

but it fails to infer the types correctly

```
const hello: number = getDeep({ hello: 1 }, ['hello'])
```

It seems like it can't infer `'hello'` as being a literal. it works when I do

```
const hello: number = getDeep({ hello: 1 }, ['hello'] as ['hello'])
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhFgAoCcD2lmgDwHkA0UiAfFALyFQQAewEAdgCYDOUA2gLoBQUPUA-FBzdeALgrVajFqwCWdAGYRkUAGIEAdJrmLlAJS69+qyjXrMoAawghU8wUbgIU6JdhysV7ArpJiArowQ8nIQDMI8-oHBdKGcnPIBAMbAMqh0UADmEMCOYLgEiCaS5kzAyHIZHCQAFKgARgBWYvhQYGhgYogAlGK5zhhuBSQA3gC+caCQUAASEAA2c6gAKuDQ5H3triBYw1AAFvOLYgCMUKMErADkBwuol+xEnIlppfuHqGJ0fgC2dUpkmWyuWquxuRygp3ObGu73uUAAhtIYbd7l1OEA)

The questions I'm left with are:

- What exactly is going on here?
- Am I approaching this from the right angle?
- Is this a hard limitation of the type system?
- Are there any open TS issues or feature requests you are aware of that attempt to solve/explain the behavior here.

Comment: Does this help https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10693 ? I think the (simplified) takeaway is that your `property` parameter is a `string[]` and somehow every element in that array has to depend on the previous one

Comment: No, the idea is exactly to avoid the amount of overloads in that issue.